# Is there a way to skip a pytest fixture?

Tags: pytest

The problem is my given fixture function has an external dependency and that is causing an "Error" (like unreachable network / insufficient resource etc).

I'd like to skip the fixture and there by skip any test that depends on this fixture.

Doing something like this wont work:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.skip(reason="Something.")
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def parametrized_username():
    raise Exception("foobar")
    return 'overridden-username'
```

this will result in

```
_______________________________ ERROR at setup of test_username _______________________________

    @pytest.mark.skip(reason="Something.")
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def parametrized_username():
>       raise Exception("foobar")
E       Exception: foobar

a2.py:6: Exception
```

What's the right away to skip a pytest fixture?

Comment: could you stuff the definition inside a `try/except` block?

Comment: @PaulH - the tests will fail. How do I skip the tests then?

Comment: I think you're going to have to mark the tests individually, or stuff inside a test class and skip that in one fell swoop

Comment: oh possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128620/in-pytest-how-to-skip-or-xfail-certain-fixtures

Comment: @PaulH - No. it is not a dupe. The suggestions given that does not work for example I gave. Try it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
    pytest.skip('Because I want so')

def test_me(myfixture):
    pass
```

---

```
$ pytest -v -s -ra r.py 
r.py::test_me SKIPPED
=========== short test summary info ===========
SKIP [1] .../r.py:6: Because I want so

=========== 1 skipped in 0.01 seconds ===========
```

Internally, `pytest.skip()` function raises an exception `Skipped`, which is inherited from `OutcomeException`. These exceptions are specially handled to simulate the test outcome, but to not fail the test (similar to `pytest.fail()`).

Comment: Thanks for educating me, @Sergey.