# Skip tests using a particular pytest fixture

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Is there a way to skip all tests using a particular (user-defined) fixture?

Consider the following example:

```
# test.py

def test_foo(resource):
    if resource is None:
       pytest.skip("Resource not available")
   
    # do the actual foo test

def test_bar(resource):
    if resource is None:
       pytest.skip("Resource not available")
   
    # do the actual bar test

# -------------------------------------------
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='package')
def resource():
    
    try:
        ret = acquire_the_expensive_resource()
    except ResourceUnavailable: 
        return None
   
    return ret
```

The tests that depend on the availability of `resource` all need to be skipped if it is unavailable.  The above implementation works fine.  But does not scale well; any test should first check if `resource` is `None` and if that's the case, get skipped using the same `skip` call.

I am looking for a way to move the 'check the availability and skip' step inside the fixture, so that it is implemented once, and propagated automatically to all tests using that fixture.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Is there a way to skip a pytest fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852934/is-there-a-way-to-skip-a-pytest-fixture)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to add to the `conftest.py` something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_by_resource(request, resource):
    closest_marker = request.node.get_closest_marker('skip_without_resource')

    if closest_marker and resource is None:
        pytest.skip("Resource not available")


def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers", "skip_without_resource: skip test if resource is not available",
    )
```

and then modify tests in `test.py`:

```py
@pytest.mark.skip_without_resource
def test_foo():
    # do the actual foo test

@pytest.mark.skip_without_resource
def test_bar():
    # do the actual bar test
```